# Number of 1's needed to write all primes up to P

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, primes

- i) Find, if it exists, a prime P such that the number of 1's used to write all the primes from 2 to P is precisely P.
- ii) Are there infinitely many such P? If not, find them all.

These questions arose during discussions at the 2023 Soacha, Colombia Math Circle.

[Here is a related question.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452879)

Comment: Does this have any practical applications?

Comment: The 'number of 1's used to write' a number is just the number of occurences of the digit 1?

Comment: The number of 1's required is the following [sequence in the oeis.](https://oeis.org/A231590) By 10^14 still far behind!

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by the number of 1s required to write a number n.

Comment: @RosieF In writing the numbers from 1 to 100, the total number of 1's used is 21. Verify!

Comment: Usually it's phrased as "the number of  the digit 1 appearing in the decimal representation in the numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), denoted by $\pi(x)$, counts the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $x$. It is closely approximated by $\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$. If we take $x=10^n$, we know that all primes in this range have at most $n$ digits. We can therefore estimate the total number of digits to be $d\approx n\times\frac{10^n}{\ln{10^n}}$. Then we take some prime $p\approx 10^n$ and find an approximate value for $\frac{d}{p}$:

> $\frac{d}{p}\approx\frac{n}{\ln{10^n}}\approx0.4343$

As this value is constant, the implication is:

> The total number of digits used to write all primes from $2$ to $p$ is less than $\frac{p}{2}$ for sufficiently large primes. The number of 1's used to write these primes is approximately one tenth of that.
>  There **does not exist** a prime $p$ for which this number is precisely $p$.

Data from the first 50 million primes, up to 982,451,653.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: This answer draws conclusion based on behavior at infinite - for big numbers - and missing terms as "probably" in it.
For a formal proof, I think one has to prove how big has to be $p$ to consider the digit count approximation to have an error such that that error prevent the digit counting function to diverge too much from its value at infinite and reach values equal to $p$. Thus I am not sure that would prove there does not exist primes with such property but a finite amount...(cont)

Comment: ...Also one has to prove that primes and their digits are acting like random numbers. [digits are not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452879/are-0-and-1-respectively-the-least-and-most-used-digits-among-primes). (ie. having primes with a lot of 1s at large number is likely as having a prime in any other allowed form).
The fair conclusion should be "**Probably**, there does not exist a prime with such property, and hardly an infinite amount."

Comment: @10010100102ohno A formal proof is not required here.  Also, the prime counting function is well studied. An upper bound for the digit count comes directly from $\pi(x)$. The total digit count remains below $0.5x$, so the distribution of digits is irrelevant.

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood your answer because the word "approximation". It's clear to me that if we speak of upper bounds your answer works great! (however $x/ln(x)$ is a lower bound for counting primes, so the sequent operation it's not an upper bound to their digits). I found [this site](https://t5k.org/howmany.html) that suggests a simple upper bound that does not change the answer conclusions: $(x/ln x)(1 + 1.2762/ln x)$ when $x>598$ @Daniel Mathias

Comment: @10010100102ohno (pedantic) An upper bound ... directly from $\pi(x)$, using the actual value, not the approximation.

Answer (score 4):

**A partial answer** with some observations about numerical behavior.

You can find the code to compute the numbers in this answer [here](https://go.dev/play/p/ay5GsvB7fqS).

- First we want to define the ratio $R_N$ as the number of ones in primes until number $N$ and the number $N$. If $R_N=1$ and $N$ is prime than we found our solutions (some or all).
- You can see from this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A231590) (thanks to @Freddy Barrera) that  $R_{10^n}$ is decreasing for n>1. However the delta from $R_{10^(n+1)}$ and $R_{10^n}$ is also decreasing and at some point it can start increasing (or reach a plateau).

[image]

- Plot of $R_N$:

> ! Plot of $R_N$ when N is prime, x axis is the i-th prime, up to the 10k
> ! [image]
> Minimas seem to occur at values just before power of 10, while maximas are around 2*power of 10

- Conjecture 1: Base 10 is peculiar and maybe the point on which $R_N >= 1$ (if exists) is at very high value of N. It's time consuming computing primes greater than 10^14 (the value from OEIS) to see patterns. And maybe the bouncing behavior is less marked in other bases.
- Conjecture 2: Lower numerical bases maybe give us a clearer $R_N$ pattern.

Let's work in base $2$, that is full of ones!

First we check if we have any solution:

> Yes, 3 5 11 19 23 47 61 are, computed up to 10^7 .

Then we want to see if $R_N$ has some patterns:

> Plot of $R_N$ when N is prime, x axis is the i-th prime, up to the 10k
>  [image]
>  Little bouncing, uh? Seems also to tend to a value...
>
>  Let's see if 100k give us more clues:
>  [image]
>  Still a little bouncing.
>  So, for the moment our best guess is that ${R_N}$ is approaching some value near 0.8

Let's compute $R_{10^n}$ in base $2$:

> N       ones    R_N 
>  10^1    8       0.8 
>  10^2    87      0.87 
>  10^3    889     0.889 
>  10^4    8437    0.8437 
>  10^5    82074   0.82074 
>  10^6    809377  0.809377 
>  10^7    7902408 0.7902408 
>  10^8    78337542        0.78337542 
>  10^9    778137796       0.778137796

Let's see if base $4$ has some similar behavior

> Plot of $R_N$ when N is prime, x axis is the i-th prime, up to the 10k
>  [image]
>  Yes, it is bouncing and tending to some values...

${R_{10^n}}$ base 4:

> 10^1    3       0.3 
>  10^2    31      0.31 
>  10^3    252     0.252 
>  10^4    2644    0.2644 
>  10^5    25265   0.25265 
>  10^6    217444  0.217444 
>  10^7    2279625 0.2279625 
>  10^8    22415398        0.22415398

Solutions in other bases:

> Not found up to 10^7 and base from 3 to 62

My best guess (aka **speculation** without mathematical proof!):

> Even in base $2$ that should be the base with the most number of ones (at least in any given random number) - both because the length of the numbers and the fact that numbers themselves are composed by only $0$s and $1$s - We observe a mostly decreasing trend in the long run, even if little bouncing, leaving me think that no more solution will be discovered after the first 7. In base $10$ this behavior could be even stronger due to the rarity of ones wrt base-2, so $R_N < 1$ for all N and no solution exists at all.

I leave for reference $R_{10^n}$ computed in bases from 3 to 62 [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tii1KHgE)